# Neighborhood vs. Neighborhood filter

Tags: general-topology, filters

Say I build some sort of Topology

If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space and $p \in X$, a $\textit{neighbourhood}$ of $p$ is a subset $V$ of $X$, in which $p \in U \subseteq V$, $U$ is open.
We say that $V$ is a $\mathcal{T}-\textit{neighbourhood}$ of $x \in X$ or that $V$ is a $\textit{neighborhood}$ of $x$.

The set of all neighbourhoods of $x \in X$, denoted $\mathcal{N}_x$ is called the $\textit{neighbourhood filter}$ of $x$.

An example of Neighborhood Filters on a Topological space. Let $X = \{a,b,c\}$ and let $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{b,c\},\{a,b\},X\}$ Let $\mathcal{N}_a = \{\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},X\}, \, \mathcal{N}_b = \{\{b\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\},X\}$, and $\mathcal{N}_{c} = \{\{b,c\},X \}$. In this example $\{a,c \}$ is a neighborhood of a but not of c. Thus a set does not have to be a neighborhood of all of its points.

What is the point of having Neighborhood Filters and what does that tell us about the Topological space, i.e. if a set does not have to be a neighborhood of all of its points, what does this mean for the Topological space? I get the feeling that neighborhoods are some sort of limit which will give us the smallest neighborhood of each point, or perhaps if a neighborhood is not that of all of its points then these points are "seperated" somehow but I am not sure (how it works).

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Neighborhood filters is used in definition of locally compact, and other "locally ..." definitions

Comment: @Minghao, thanks - I am not sure what you mean by "locally ...". Looking at definitions though (and other Stack questions) I see that $X$ is locally compact $\Leftrightarrow$ each $x \in X$ has a basis of compact neighbourhoods. Now I know that compact means that a Topological space $X$ is compact if each of its open covers has a finite subcover. So does this mean that each of the neighborhoods of a point $p$ have to have finite subcovers themselves? Would they already have that though if the whole Top. space $X$ has a finite cover itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can specify a topology in more than four different ways. The standard definition specifies the open sets, what we usually call a "topology." The second way is to specify the close sets-this is of course only a trivial difference. The third way is to specify a closure operation on subsets of your space, and the fourth is to specify a neighborhood filter for every point satisfying the natural axiom that every neighborhood of $x$ is a neighborhood of every point of one of its subsets. So in this sense neighborhood filters tell you everything they possibly could about a topological space.

Probably the best way to think about the neighborhood filter of $x$: is that it contains all information regarding convergence to $x$. In the first topological spaces one encounters, convergence is usually of sequences. But this isn't enough to describe the topology in arbitrary spaces, for instance the infinite-dimensional spaces of functional analysis. It becomes important to speak of convergence of *nets*, or of *filters.* A filter on $X$ is just a nontrivial subset of the powerset of $X$ closed under finite intersection and superset, and a filter converges to a point $x$ if and only if it contains the neighborhood filter of $x$. In contrast to the case with sequences, this is enough to specify a topology: in fact it's enough to describe how *ultrafilters*, that is, maximal filters, converge. So in this sense the neighborhood filter encapsulates the viewpoint that topology generalizes the study of convergent sequences.

Just to comment on your thoughts: in a sense the neighborhood filter describes the smallest neighborhood of a point-except that there is no smallest neighborhood! That's true, at least, in many of the most interesting spaces, and is the main reason to worry about a whole filter of neighborhoods-if there were a smallest neighborhood then in any hypothesis requiring something to hold on a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x$ we could just pick the smallest neighborhood. But the smallest neighborhood of a point must be contained in the intersection of all its neighborhoods, and in, say, a Hausdorff space the intersection of all neighborhoods of $x$ is $\{x\}$, which is not a neighborhood of $x$ when $x$ is not isolated. So the filter functions as a *virtual* smallest neighborhood of $x$: it doesn't converge to a neighborhood of $x$, so we can't think about its limit, but functionally we do just that.